# how can i create user profile links?

Tags: php

I have a profile.php wich echo the user info i want. After searching alittle on google and watching a few tutorials, im stuck. I want every user registered to my website to get a profile (unique), that is access able for everyone. The link i plan on using is example.com/user/id where "id" is replaced with the id of the users profile you want to view.

**Register.php**

```
    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            die("<div class='red'>Please enter a username.</div>"); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("<div class='red'>Please enter a password.</div>"); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("<div class='red'>Invalid E-Mail Address</div>"); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this.
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("<div class='red'>Failed to run query: </div>" . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("<div class='red'>This username is already in use</div>"); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("<div class='red'>Failed to run query: </div>" . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("<div class='red'>This email address is already registered</div>"); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read.
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("<div class='red'>Failed to run query:</div> " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: /login"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to /login"); 
    } 

?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php 
    // This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
    // login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here 
    // to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form. 
    $submitted_username = ''; 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
        // their username. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                bio,
                warnings,
                clan,
                timestamp,
                title,
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("<div class='red'>Failed to run query: </div>" . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
        // they entered is not registered. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        { 
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
            // sensitive values first. 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
            header("Location: /"); 
            die("Redirecting to: /"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            print("<div class='red'>Login Failed.</div>"); 

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
            // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should 
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information: 
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 

?>
```

**Profile.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--START HEAD-->
    <?php include 'head.php'; ?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="/profile.css"/>

    <title><?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>'s profile</title>
<!--END HEAD-->
</head>
<body>
<!--START BODY-->
<?php
    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        include'navigationbar.php';
    } else {
        include'navigationbar2.php';
    }
?>
<!--MAIN CONTENT-->
<div class="movedown"></div>
<div class="content">

<!--MAIN PROFILE-->
<div class="username">
<?php if(empty($_SESSION['user']['clan'])){
    print "";
}else{
    print "[".htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['clan'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."]";} ?>


<?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
<div class="fr">ID: <?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></div></div>
<div class="spacing"></div>


<div class="fl">
<!--AVATAR-->
<div class="avatarback">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="/profile/avatar/default.jpg" width="180px"/></div>
</div>



<!--TITLES / SIGNS-->
<div class="signs"><br/>
    <div class="title"><div class="fl">Title:       </div>
<div class="fr"><?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>       </div></div><!--TITLE-->
        <div class="spacing"></div>


    <div class="warnings"><div class="fl">Warnings: </div>
<div class="fr"><?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['warnings'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>    </div></div><!--WARNINGS-->
        <div class="spacing"></div> 


    <div class="joined"><div class="fl">Joined:     </div>
<div class="fr"><?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['timestamp'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>   </div></div><!--JOINED-->
</div>
</div>



<div class="padding"></div>

<!--BIO-->
<div class="bioback">
<?php if(empty($_SESSION['user']['bio'])){
    print "This user has not set any bio yet...";
}else{
    print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>
</div>


<!--SETTINGS TAB-->
<div class="etc-back">
<div><a href="/messages">Message</a></div>
    <div class="spacing2"></div>    
<div><a href="/settings">Settings</a></div>
    <div class="spacing2"></div>    
<div><a href="/adminpanel">AdminPanel</a></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="email">
<div class="fl">E-mail:</div><div class="fr"><?php print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></div>
</div>



<div class="spacing"></div>
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="email">
<div class="fl">Website:</div><div class="fr"><?php print "<a href='". htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."'>".htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."</a>"; ?></div>
</div>


<div class="spacing"></div>
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="email">
<div class="fl">Clan Page:</div><div class="fr"><?php if(empty($_SESSION['user']['clanpage'])){
    print "No Clan Page Found!";
}else{
    print htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['clanpage'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?></div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a `user.php` file and then using `$_GET['userid']`, you just extract the information from database like: `SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = '$userid' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Use `$_GET` and pass the ID through the URL query? See http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: @peixotorms but how can i use it in a url and have .htaccess rewrite it?
I want the url to have /user/id instead of user?id= i have seen tutorials where they get the link /user.php?id= but i dont know how they create the links, and i find it hard watching youtube tutorials from 2010 because the codes are old and because of my lack of experience with php im not able to rewrite it all the time

Comment: Something like this: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)\/$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: @peixotorms ooh, thanks alot. ill try it :)

Comment: @navnav $_GET gives me error (Undefined index) how do i fix this?